# Discard functions with wrong symmetry?

Tags: programming, trigonometry, symmetry

I have functions of `x`, where `x` is the polar angle of spherical coordinates, i.e. `0 < x < Pi`. Some of the functions are of even symmetry about the equator `x = Pi/2` (such as `Sin[x]`), and other functions are of odd symmetry about `x = Pi/2` (such as `Sin[x]Cos[x]` )  (Just `Plot` them to see.)  Can one use Mathematica to eliminate odd functions from a sum of even and odd functions?  For example, as a test, can one eliminate the odd function from the sum `Sin[x] + Sin[x]Cos[x]`?

Comment: Note, even symmetry about $x=\pi/2$ is equivalent to odd symmetry about $x=0$, so doesn't the standard $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$ work?

Comment: No, I don't think that works.  Sin[x] is even about Pi/2 and odd about 0, while Sin[x]*Cos[x] is odd about both Pi/2 and 0. But something along that reasoning should work.  I guess this is probably not really a Mathematica problem.

Comment: The trick works for symmetry about other $x$ than 0: `antisymmetrize[expr_, {x_, x0_}] := (expr - (expr /. x -> 2 x0 - x))/2`

Comment: As a general group theory problem, this can be done by using projectors onto the irreducible representations of the symmetry group in question. It's certainly not specifically a *Mathematica* problem, but I remember discussing another example in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7822/245).

Comment: I think that if we have the general function F[x] for 0 < x < Pi, we can easily get the symmetric part of F[x] by using (F[x] + F[Pi - x])/2 , basically the idea of @rcollyer above.  By symmetry here, I mean symmetry about x = Pi/2. I will check to see if the other ways above work.

Comment: A general approach for working with actions of finite groups is described at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13851.  The generalization of "eliminate the odd function" is obtained by averaging over the group (weighting by a group character).

Comment: As @Jens has written and as added by @whuber, one can average over the group. The group is here Cs (or Ci), which consists of two elements: identical and the mirror reflection in the equatorial plane. The latter transformation one achieves by the replacement `x->Pi-x`. That is, `f[x]->f[\[Pi]-x]`. The averaging one achieves by `1/2 (f[x] + f[\[Pi] - x])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(* Check if f is odd/even around an interval of length d centered around c *)
evenQ[f_, c_: Pi/2, d_: Pi] := Integrate[Abs[f[c + x] - f[c - x]], {x, 0, d/2}] == 0
oddQ[f_, c_: Pi/2, d_: Pi]  := Integrate[Abs[f[c + x] + f[c - x]], {x, 0, d/2}] == 0

sum = Sin[x] + Sin[x] Cos[x] + Cos[x] + Exp[x]
(* Sum to list, elements to functions, remove odd ones, back to sum *)
Plus @@ DeleteCases[Map[Function[x, #] &, List @@ sum], _?(oddQ[#] &)]
% /. Function[x, f_] :> f

(* Function[x, E^x] + Function[x, Sin[x]] *)
(* E^x + Sin[x] *)
```

I wanted `oddQ` and `evenQ` to take a function as argument so there is some mucking about making the expression in the sum into functions.

If you want to keep only even functions (that is, not leave stuff like `Exp` in) use `Cases[..., _?(evenQ[#]&)]` instead.

If the functions are slow to integrate change to `NIntegrate` with some appropriate `AccuracyGoal`

Comment: Thanks @ssch. That seems like a very nice general way to do this.  I'll check it out. But for this limited case, wouldn't it be easier to just use the formula for F[x] above?

Comment: @Skybobcat That would be way better indeed :)