# Calculate representations of $SU(N)$ generators

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I would like to calculate explicit representations of certain $SU(N)$ generators. I have written some code, but either it is extremely slow, or something just doesn't work. Either way, I would be very happy for some input!

Back to topic: The generators are hermitian, traceless $d\times d$ matrices $t^a$ ($a=1,\ldots,N^2-1$), 
$$ t^a = (t^a)^\dagger = ((t^a)^T)^*,\qquad \text{Tr}[t^a]=0 $$
where $d$ depends on the representation. They should also fulfill their algebra relation
$$ [t^a,t^b]:=t^a t^b - t^b t^a = \text{i} \sum\limits_{c=1}^{N^2-1}f^{abc} t^c $$
where $f^{abc}$ are known constants ("structure constants"). My code looks like this:

```
(* Specify SU(n) *)
n = 2; 
(* rep(resentation) will determine dim(ension) *)
rep = "fund"; 
(* range for index a *)
dimSU = n^2 - 1; 
(* Define structure constants *)
f[a_, b_, c_] := Switch[n, 2, LeviCivitaTensor[3][[a]][[b]][[c]]]
(* Define dim depending on rep *)
dim := Switch[rep, "trivial", 1, "fund", 2, "adj", 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
(* Define matrices t^a with indices {ij} *)
t[a_, i_, j_] := Table[
       tt[a, i, j]    (* They are the variables I want to work with *)
       , {ii, 1, dim}
      , {jj, 1, dim}
     , {aa, 1, dimSU}][[a]][[i]][[j]]
(* Print t as a list *)
tMatrix[a_] := Table[t[a, i, j], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}]
(* Print t as a matrix *)
tMatrixForm[a_] := 
 Table[t[a, i, j], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}] // MatrixForm
```

Now I implement the equations that they have to fulfill:

```
requireTraceless = 
  Table[Sum[tt[a, i, i], {i, 1, dim}] == 0, {a, 1, dimSU}];
requireHermitean = Table[
     tt[a, i, j] == Conjugate[tt[a, j, i]]
     , {i, 1, j}
    , {j, 1, dim}
   , {a, 1, dimSU}];
requireLie = Table[
     Sum[t[a, i, j] t[Mod[a, dimSU] + 1, j, k], {j, 1, dim}] - 
       Sum[t[Mod[a, dimSU] + 1, i, j] t[a, j, k], {j, 1, dim}] == 
      I f[a, Mod[a, dimSU] + 1, Mod[a + 1, dimSU] + 1] t[
        Mod[a + 1, dimSU] + 1, i, k]
     , {i, 1, dim}
    , {k, 1, dim}
   , {a, 1, dimSU}];
```

Finally I collect my equations and variables.

```
varList = 
  Table[tt[a, i, j], {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}, {a, 1, 
     dimSU}] // Flatten;
eqList = {requireTraceless, requireHermitean, requireLie} // Flatten;
```

And try to solve.

```
Solve[eqList, varList]
```

For $SU(2)$ with `dim=2`, this should yield the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

I have found a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/package-for-representation-of-groups-group-theory), although it only covers the case $N=2$. Also, I would like to learn how/why my code is so slow.

edit: included info from comments

Comment: The repeated `Table[]` calls certainly do not help. Why not put it as a single `Table[]`, e.g. `Table[tt[a, i, j], {a, 1, dimSU}, {j, 1, dim}, {i, 1, dim}]` instead of `Table[Table[Table[tt[a, i, j], {i, 1, dim}], {j, 1, dim}], {a, 1, dimSU}]`?

Comment: Considering the link to the spin operators: Do not mix up $SU(N)$ with the spin group $\operatorname{Spin}(N)$. Are you really looking for certain generators of the _Lie algebra_ of $SU(N)$ or for generators of _representations_ of the spin group?

Comment: @J.M. I did not know about that! Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher it's about generators of SU(N), thanks for the clarification!

Comment: That's really many equations, many due to the requirement of being (skew-)Hermitian. (The generators of $SU(N)$ should be skew-Hermitian. I know, physicists like to multiply everything by $\operatorname{i}$.) You can get rid of  these equations  by realizing that you only have to set up variables for the upper triangular part of the generators and "reflect" them to the lower triangular part with `ConjugateTranspose`.

Comment: That‘s a great idea, thanks!

Comment: Note that the basis of generators is uniquely determined by the structure constants alone. If the set of solutions contains, e.g., a continuous one-parameter family, this may cause trouble when trying to solve these equations.

Comment: do your programs apply to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214397/141334 ? please illuminate if you can - thanks! +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the idea of the structure constants is not to prescribe them and then to find a suitable basis. It is vice versa: Usually, one prescribes a basis satisfying some niceness requirements and computes the structure constants from them. Oftentimes, these requirements are sparsity and orthonormality with respect to some inner product.

Sparse matrices are best set up with `SparseArray`. Here, I construct a sparse basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ which is orthonormal with respect to the Frobenius inner product. Of course, the method works for all dimension.

```
n = 3;
a = 1/Sqrt[2] Flatten[Table[SparseArray[{{i, j} -> I, {j, i} -> I}, {n, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1];
b = 1/Sqrt[2] Flatten[Table[SparseArray[{{i, j} -> -1, {j, i} -> 1}, {n, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1];
c = DiagonalMatrix@*SparseArray /@ Orthogonalize[Table[SparseArray[{{i} -> I, {i + 1} -> -I}, {n}], {i, 1, n - 1}]];
basis = Join[a, b, c];
MatrixForm /@ basis
```

[image]

Up to ordering, scaling, and a multiplication with the imaginary unit, these are the [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices).

Testing if we really have elements of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$:

```
Max[Abs[Tr /@ basis]]
Max[Abs[basis + ConjugateTranspose /@ basis]]

(* 0 *)
(* 0 *)
```

Testing the orthonormality:

```
innerprod = {x, y} \[Function] Tr[x.ConjugateTranspose[y]];
Outer[innerprod, basis, basis, 1] == IdentityMatrix[n (n - 1) + (n - 1)]
(* True *)
```

Orthogonality is a nice feature since the structure constants can now be computed with

```
SparseArray@ Outer[{x, y, z} \[Function] innerprod[x.y - y.x, z], basis, basis, basis, 1]
```

Comment: Creating a basis with SparseArray and Orthogonalize is really elegant, thank you for showing how it works! However, how would I proceed in order to find a 4x4 dimensional representation that also fulfill $su(3)$ relations like the Gell-Mann matrices? That was what I originally intended to do using `n` to specify the algebra $su(n)$ and `dim` which would specify the dimension of the representation.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest for you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984558/a-4x4-matrix-representation-of-su3

Comment: Had to think about it but yeah, this was very interesting, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Does your method work for this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214397/141334  ?

Comment: also thanks I voted up for this nice post (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214397/141334)

Comment: maybe you guys can help on this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658496/310987