# Packages for study presentation of groups

Tags: matrix, packages, group-theory

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45879/8822) question asks if there are tools/packages in Mathematica for the study of presentation of groups, but it is almost 7 years old and an answer suggests to use *Combinatorica* package which is now deprecated.

Are there more up to date packages or built-in functionality for the study of presentations of a group?

I use version 11.3

Comment: I suppose that you should take a look on Gap that may fit your needs better. The software tool can be found at https://www.gap-system.org. There exists also an interface from Sage to Gap that may be more user friendly, but according to my knowledge, it restricts its extent. For that reasons I prefer to work with Gap.

Comment: I think the software [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/) might be more powerful.